# Detect iPhone iOS version that is connected to the Mac

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, iokit

I'm really interested in knowing how to get an iPhone's iOS version that is connected to a Mac, I'm guessing I'll need to use IOKit, it contains a constant known as 'kOSBuildVersionKey'. Is this the constant I need to use?

Comment: I don't see a kOSBuildVersionKey property on the IOKit USB device nub for a connected iPhone7, at least not on OS X 10.11. There's an "OS Build Version" property on the *I/O registry root node*, which is just the build for the OS X (Mac!) version of IOKit you're running, and which has nothing to do with the iPhone. You might have more luck at the usbmux level, but I don't know anything about that.

Comment: I found the following websites which are related to all this stuff: https://github.com/samdmarshall/SDMMobileDevice                                         https://gist.github.com/JRHeaton/1303158

Comment: This project solved all of my problems :                                                      https://github.com/osxusr/DeviceUtilz